# show the value on the each color of stacked bar chart from a different column of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-analysis

This is my data frame:

```
          6month  final-formula     Question Text  numPatients6month
286231       1       0.031730        CI_FINANCE                977
286270       1       0.147390            CI_MJO                977
286276       1       0.106448  CI_CONCENTRATING                977
286700       2       0.010323            CI_MJO                775
286323       2       0.018065        CI_FINANCE                775
286401       2       0.034839  CI_CONCENTRATING                775
286228       3       0.032020  CI_CONCENTRATING                812
286238       3       0.061576            CI_MJO                812
286292       3       0.008621        CI_FINANCE                812
286690       4       0.008097            CI_MJO                741
286342       4       0.005398        CI_FINANCE                741
286430       4       0.060729  CI_CONCENTRATING                741
286481       5       0.009840        CI_FINANCE                813
287441       5       0.008610            CI_MJO                813
286362       5       0.041820  CI_CONCENTRATING                813
286360       6       0.021622  CI_CONCENTRATING                740
286492       6       0.017568        CI_FINANCE                740
286494       6       0.014865            CI_MJO                740
286482       7       0.015464        CI_FINANCE                776
286483       7       0.042526            CI_MJO                776
286599       7       0.011598  CI_CONCENTRATING                776
286361       8       0.024490  CI_CONCENTRATING                735
286989       8       0.004082        CI_FINANCE                735
286402       8       0.021769            CI_MJO                735
287119       9       0.003916        CI_FINANCE                766
286408       9       0.011749            CI_MJO                766
286399       9       0.019582  CI_CONCENTRATING                766
286267      10       0.019337  CI_CONCENTRATING                724
286249      10       0.037293            CI_MJO                724
286810      10       0.008287        CI_FINANCE                724
```

I have plotted this data frame as stacked bar chart.
this stacked bar chart is based on `(6month,final-formula)`.

As you see there is `numPatients6month` in the data frame.
I would like to show this number on each category of stacked bar.
for example:

this is my barchart:
[image]

so according to stacked bar above, I want to show `977` in the first bar the blue color, show 977 for the `CI_Finance` which is `orange color`.

**It is different from** [this](https://community.tableau.com/thread/212880) question, as it isnt stacked bar,
Also **different from** [this](https://community.tableau.com/thread/212880), as I am going to show another column`(numPatients6month)` which is in my data frame, not the column in `y-axis`.
y-axis is `final-formula`, but I would like to show `numPatients6month` on each color of each stacked bar.

Just as information, I have plotted the above using this code:

```
df = dffinal.drop('numPatients6month', 1).groupby(['6month','Question Text']).sum().unstack('Question Text')

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
ax=df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xticks(range(0,10), ['6month','1 year','1.5 year','2 year','2.5 year','3 year','3.5 year','4 year','4.5 year','5 year'], fontsize=8, rotation=45)

plt.title('Cognitive Impairement-Stack bar')
plt.show()
```

Thanks, :)

Comment: So you want three times the same number in each bar? Once in blue, once in orange, once in green?

Comment: SpghttCd thanks for the response, this data frame has the same number, but it may be different. any number in the column numPatients6month for each Question Text. so there is three Question text so three number, however the number should be called from numPatients6month

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is one way to do it:

```
ax=df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
#loop to add the text
list_values = (dffinal['numPatients6month'].tolist()[::3] 
                + dffinal['numPatients6month'].tolist()[1::3] 
                + dffinal['numPatients6month'].tolist()[2::3])
for rect, value in zip(ax.patches, list_values):
    h = rect.get_height() /2.
    w = rect.get_width() /2.
    x, y = rect.get_xy()
    ax.text(x+w, y+h,value,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')
#same than your code
plt.xticks(range(0,10), ['6month','1 year','1.5 year','2 year','2.5 year','3 year','3.5 year','4 year','4.5 year','5 year'], fontsize=8, rotation=45)
plt.title('Cognitive Impairement-Stack bar')
plt.show()
```

The `list_values` is to get the value from the column 'numPatients6month' in the same order than the `rect` from `ax.patches`  and the result is:

[image]

but because some bars are small the results is not really easy to read.

EDIT: about the loop, `ax.patches` contains informations about all the bar you plot, so for each bar that I named `rect`, with `get_xy` you get the position of the bottom left corner of the bar, and with `get_height` (r. `get_width`) get the height (r. width) of the bar. so (x+w, y+h) gives the coordinates of the middle of the bar, where you add the text `value` (from `list_values`) with the function `ax.text` (parameters `horizontalalignment` and `verticalalignment` are to center the text)

EDIT 2: more general method, thanks to @SpghttCd for getting `list_values`

```
list_values = (dffinal.drop('final-formula', 1).groupby(['6month','Question Text']).sum()
               .unstack('Question Text').fillna(0).astype(int).values.flatten('F'))
for rect, value in zip(ax.patches, list_values):
    if value != 0:
        h = rect.get_height() /2.
        w = rect.get_width() /2.
        x, y = rect.get_xy()
        ax.text(x+w, y+h,value,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')
```

Comment: cheers to the response :) only one thing, I have other data frame which does not have the same number for each color. does this method still works?

Comment: It would be awesome if you can explain the for loop part. Im not sure I can understand it fully :)

Comment: T thanks so much, so I applied your approach on thedifferent data frame, the result was a bit not correct or better say it should be better if it was more general approach. the difference in this data frame was that one bar may have one colour, two colour or three colour. actually it is the same df except that some of the data related to the category may be zero so there should not be the colour related to them in the bar.

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the x- and y-positions of the labels directly from your dataset:

```
x_lbl = dffinal['6month'].values - 1
y_lbl = (df.cumsum(axis=1) - df/2).values.flatten()
```

The arrangement of the labels can be done the same way you did for your data:

```
df_lbl = dffinal.drop('final-formula', 1).groupby(['6month','Question Text']).sum().unstack('Question Text')
lbl = df_lbl.values.flatten()
```

and then just loop over the lists of your x-, y- and label-arrays:

```
for x, y, txt in zip(x_lbl, y_lbl, lbl):
    plt.text(x, y, txt, va='center', ha='center')
```

[image]